# Read HTTP request headers, and modify response headers of an Apps Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script

Can I modify the HTTP response headers to add cookies and extra information? Also I'm having troubles reading the request headers.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47634044/1595451

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot read or set HTTP Headers in a Apps Script app deployed as a web app. You are restricted to reading the query string or the post values for GET/POST respectively. When responding you can only return the content and the MIME type (restricted to a [few](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contentservice_mimetype) types)

This is because the scripts are served off the Google.com domain and you should not have  ways to set/get cookies that could potentially be used for malicious reasons.

However, if you are using [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch) within an Apps Script app to make outbound calls, you have much more control of the HTTP headers

Comment: I'm trying to use Apps Script as Asana webhooks endpoint (https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/webhooks). So if I understand you correctly it is not possible? Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357834/can-i-use-google-apps-script-as-asana-webhooks-endpoint-dopost/
Please also read my comment under the question.