# Can I use Google Apps Script as Asana Webhooks endpoint (doPost)?

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks, asana-api, asana-connect

I'm trying to connect **Google Docs** with [Asana](https://app.asana.com/). I can create tasks from **Google Docs** and save the connection to **MySql** database so I can display tasks inside **Google Document**.

Now I need those tasks to be synced with **Asana** all the time, so I wanted to create [Asana webhooks](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/webhooks). I created a [doPost funtion](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) in **Google Apps Script** which should serve as an endpoint. But when I initiate the starting handshake I don't receive a request from **Asana** to my **Google Web App**.

To be sure I'm doing everything right I also created a handshake in **PHP**, which I'm more familiar with. The only problem I had was a **SSL certificate**. But I think that shouldn't be the problem with **Google**. And also my **Google Web App** is public so there shouldn't be any restrictions (I tested it with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). I'm receiving requests from **Postman**. To be sure I receive a request I also created a log into a **Google Document**.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it was a Google Apps Script code refresh/update problem. It started working after a day. I don't see another explanation, because I didn't change anything in the code, just repeated the handshake test after a day with the same code. Now I still have a problem with reading POST request headers. I don't find a way to do that in Google Apps Script.

Comment: Glad to hear the handshake is now working with Asana. Let us know if you have any other issues with it.

Comment: The handshake is actually not possible between Asana and Google Apps Script because there is no way to set and read request headers. I'll put my research in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Google Apps Script cannot be used as Asana Webhooks endpoint.

**Long answer:**

You can receive post requests to Google Apps Script with doPost function. So the first two steps of [Asana Webhooks handshake](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/webhooks#create) can be accomplished. But there is no way to send a proper response for the third step of the handshake, because you can't read headers of the post request received from Asana and you also can't set the headers of the response back to Asana. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849219/5068563) I have found about reading and setting headers in Google Apps Script.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the in-depth research! I've added this to our Asana internal project for API opportunities; perhaps if we find that enough people have this problem, we can implement the handshake slightly differently, such as sending and receiving the handshake key in the body of the handshake request.