# Access request headers in doPost()

Tags: google-apps-script

To verify a webhook i need to get a parameter from the request headers. So far i couldn't find any information if it is actually possible to access these headers within Apps Scripts. Only thing that works so far is accessing the body of the post request.

```
function doPost(e) {
    // something like this
    var headerParam = e.headers['Content-Type'];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible with `doPost()` triggers. However there is a pending feature request for this issue on Google's issue tracker. If you'd like to see this feature supported please leave a comment (on the issue thread linked below) and be sure to **STAR** the issue at the following link:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67764685

The workaround I currently use is to leverage Google Cloud Functions. I wrote a related article about it [here](https://gist.github.com/DimuDesigns/7b49c9fe4de79f851fbeaa4cb18d0126).